# How to get object with key and value using Jquery each method..?

Tags: jquery, json, foreach

I am not able to get a key and value pairs using the each function of jquery. How to get the key and values object using jQuery each function..?

my try:

```
var result = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(n, v) {
    console.log({n: v});
});
```

result i am getting as:

```
Object {n: "John"} 
Object {n: "Doe"} 
Object {n: "johndoe@johndoe.com"} 
Object {n: "123 dead drive"}
```

but i am looking for :

```
    Object {FirstName: "John"} 
    Object {LastName: "Doe"} 
    Object {Email: "johndoe@johndoe.com"} 
    Object {Phone: "123 dead drive"}
```

what is the correct approach to get this done..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(n, v) {
    console.log('{'+n +': '+ v +'}');    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(n, v) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[n] = v;
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(n, v) {
    console.log(n +":"+ v );
});
```

`{}` treated as `object`.You log variable as `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var resultJSON = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';

var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    alert(k + ': ' + v);
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6PcJP/2/)

Answer (score -1):

will give the desired output

```
var arr = [];

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(n, v) {
        arr[n] = v;    
    });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This will not work, because basic array cannot be associative. You need `arr = {};` here.

Comment: It is giving the desired output

Comment: There is no need for `<code>` tags, simply indent with 4 spaces.